# Composer cannot find Git windows 8

Tags: php, git, zend-framework, github

I am just getting into PHP with Netbeans 8.0.2 and it seems I need git with composer.

However, when trying to download the Zend Framework Skeleton app starter tutorial, I get this error from composer

> [RuntimeException]
>   Failed to clone git@github.com:zendframework/zend-feed.git, git was
>   not fou     nd, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.
>   'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

So I have installed git and I have put the cmd directory into my PATH environment

[image]

However, I am still get the same error above when trying to download the Skeleton.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I see your first ";" is "；"...

Comment: Also not sure what ` for PHP\`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy that is something to with mySQL and doctorine.

Comment: @coderz changed it to ; but nothing, is it the value that could be wrong, I haven't missed any other steps out right?

Comment: OK you guys were right, the MySQL key I stated must have messed up the value. once I took it away, it worked

Answer (score 1):

That's the `bin` folder that you should put in the path.

Ps: For an easy installation, feel free to use https://chocolatey.org/

Comment: Thanks for the chocolatey - bit too late but thanks!